# Oracle: merge two rows

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

I have a pairs of related rows in my table.

How to merge these rows:

```
date                         col1 col2
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000  A    50
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000  A    -50
```

to one row

```
date                         col1 col2 col3
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000  A    50   -50
```

if there can be a small difference between two dates (about one seconds and it occurs in 1 of 100 pairs only)? e.g.:

```
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000
2012-09-11 13:28:22.0000000
```

or in worse case, one second change whole minute:

```
2012-09-11 13:28:59.0000000
2012-09-11 13:29:00.0000000
```

**update (string column):**

how to merge the same lines with an additional col3 with string values?

```
date                         col1 col2 col4
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000  A    50   abc
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000  A    -50  def
```

to:

```
date                         col1 col2 col3 col5 col6
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000  A    50   -50  abc  def
```

or to:

```
date                         col1 col2 col3 col5
2012-09-11 13:28:21.0000000  A    50   -50  abc,def
```

**solution (string)** (extension of hkutluays answer):

```
max(case when col2 > 0 then col4 end) col5
max(case when col2 < 0 then col4 end) col6
```

Comment: Do you want negative values on col3 or just want second value on col3? what if there is a more than 2 rows?

Comment: Are you really using Oracle **8i**. That has *long* been de-supported.

Comment: @hkutluay: good question, negative value in col3

Comment: @horse: really, because of some old application, which isn't supported on newer version of oracle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but may solve the problem.

```
select 
round(sysdate,'MI'),col1, sum( case when col2> 0 then col2 else 0 end ) col2,
sum( case when col2 < 0 then col2 else 0 end ) col3
from table
group by round(sysdate,'MI'),col1
```